# Run Two Instances of Kindle.app on OS X

Tags: macos, kindle

Sometimes, when reading books on my laptop (running OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion) I would like to view two separate pages from a book in my Kindle library (or two separate books) at the same time. Unfortunately, the app does not allow more than one window open at once. To get around this, I tried creating a second instance of Kindle.app called Kindle2.app. However, when I try to open it while the first one is open, the icon just bounces in the dock and then disappears. I tried changing the **CFBundleIdentifier** field in Kindle2.app/Contents/Info.plist, which is an approach I have used to allow 2 copies of nvALT to run at once. However, this does not solve the problem. What should I do?

PS I know I can use Kindle Cloud Reader, but I would like to run a second instance of the app.

Comment: One idea that, unfortunately, does not work is to download one copy from Amazon.com and one from the App Store. Still no dice.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this.
First open up the OSX kindle reader in the normal way. Then:

1. Use the online kindle cloud reader in addition.

or

2. Download the windows reader and use wineskin to open an instance. This actually works flawlessly. It is necessary sometimes as the online reader can not read all kindle books at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can open easily another instance from the commandline:

```
open -n /Applications/Kindle.app
```

It will create a second instance of the app.

**UPDATE**

You could maybe also use another reader for the second book.

For example the [Kindle Cloud Reader](http://read.amazon.com).
You can read the second book directly in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris. However, just tried it and it does the same thing as when I click-- icon bounces for a second and then disappears. Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can also use the kindle-cloud reader to read the second/same book in a webbrowser. Maybe not really comfortable, but so you would be able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Since 10.8, sandboxed applications have crashed on launch if their Info.plist has been modified. To prevent it, you can disable sandboxing by replacing the code signature with an ad-hoc signature:

```
cp -r /Applications/Kindle.app /Applications/Kindle2.app
defaults write /Applications/Kindle2.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier my.kindle
codesign -f -s - /Applications/Kindle2.app
```

When I opened Kindle2.app, it used `~/Library/Preferences/my.kindle.plist` instead of `~/Library/Containers/com.amazon.Kindle/Data/Library/Preferences/com.amazon.Kindle.plist` as the preference file. I still wasn't able to open Kindle.app and Kindle2.app at the same time though.

Comment: Running the `codesign` command, I got the following output: `/Applications/Kindle2.app: replacing existing signature
/Applications/Kindle2.app: code object is not signed at all`. This app was downloaded from the App Store, rather than from Amazon.com.